# Asynchronous NAnt batch call

Tags: batch-file, nant

In my NAnt project, I'd like to fire off a batch file and just forget about it. So I tried pulling something like this:

```
<exec program="start" commandline="cmd /c c:\mybat.bat" />
```

But NAnt complains:

```
'start' failed to start
    The system cannot find the specified fileBlockquote
```

start cmd /c c:\mybat.bat works if I run it straight from the command line. Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this [AsyncExec task](http://jayflowers.com/WordPress/?p=101). Also, IIRC `start` is not a real program but a command, which is why you're getting that error.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler alternative to use it the:

```
<exec ... pidproperty="pid1" spawn="true" />
<exec ... pidproperty="pid2" spawn="true" />
<exec ... pidproperty="pid3" spawn="true" />
<waitforexit pid="${pid1}" />
<waitforexit pid="${pid2}" />
<waitforexit pid="${pid3}" />
```

See [NAnt exec task](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/exec.html) and [NAntContrib waitforexit task](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/waitforexit.html)